# Integration test using EmbeddedKafka: ContainerTestUtil.waitForAssignment throws Expected 1 but got 0 partitions

Tags: spring-boot, spring-kafka, partitioning, embedded-kafka

I have written an integration test for my kafka consumer using spring boot, with the spring-kafka libraries. This test uses EmbeddedKafka. A topic with one partition is used. I used the KafkaMessageListener container for this. But I am getting an error in this line

```
ContainerTestUtils.waitForAssignment(container, embeddedKafkaBroker.getPartitionsPerTopic())
```

The error that I am getting is:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected 1 but got 0 partitions.

The code which I referred to is: https://blog.mimacom.com/testing-apache-kafka-with-spring-boot-junit5/

```
@EmbeddedKafka (partitions 1, ports = 9092) 
@SpringBoot Test (properties="spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers=${spring.embedded.kakfa.brokers}")

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)

@DirtiesContext

@Profile("test") 
@TestPropertySource({"classpath:application.yaml"}}

public class Onboarding ConsumerListenerTest {

BlockingQueue<ConsumerRecord<String, String> records;

KafkaMessageListenerContainer<String, String> container;

@Autowired

protected EmbeddedkafkaBroker embeddedKafkaBroker;

public ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory;

@Value("${spring.kafka.client_topic}")

private String topicName;

@Value("${spring.kafka.group_id})
private String groupId;

@Before
public void setUp(){
    
    consumerFactory = getKafkaConsumer(embeddedKafkaBroker, groupId, topicName);
    ContainerProperties containerProperties = new ContainerProperties(topicName);
    container = new KafkaMessageListenerContainer<>(consumerFactory, containerProperties);
    consumerRecords = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
    container.setupMessageListener(new MessageListener<String, String>(){
        @Override
        public void onMessage(ConsumerRecord<String, String> record){
            records.add(record);
        }
    });
    
    container.start();
    ContainerTestUtils.waitForAssignment(container, embeddedKafkaBroker.getPartitionsPerTopic());
}
}
```

And the getKafkaConsumer() function is:

```
public ConsumerFactory<String, String> 
                             getKafkaConsumer(EmbeddedKafkaBroker 
                               embeddedKafkaBroker,
                               String group,
                               String topic){
        Map<string, Object> consumerProps = 
        KafkaTestUtils.consumerProps(group, "false", 
                                     embeddedkafkaNroker);
       consumerProps.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOSTRAP_SERVER_CONFIG, 
                           embeddedKafkaBroker.getBrokerAsString());
       consumerProps.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "latest");
       consumerProps.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
       consumerProps.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_COFIG, KafkaAvroDeserializer.class);
       consumerProps.put("schema.registry.url", "bogus");
       consumerProps.put("specific.avro.reader", true);
       ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory = new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<String, String>(consumerProps);
       return consumerFactory;
}
```

Comment: You need to show the complete test as well as the full stack trace.

Comment: @GaryRussell I have added the test code. As for the stack trace, the test fails only in the CI pipeline and hence couldn't find the exact stack trace which led to the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is hard to say what is happening without more information.

An alternative is to manually assign the partitions instead of waiting for group management to assign them:

```
ContainerProperties containerProperties = 
    new ContainerProperties(new TopicPartitionOffset(topicName, 0), 
                            new TopicPartitionOffset(topicName, 1));
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That solved the issue!

Answer (score 0):

It can happen when consumer/listener is configured with autoStartup=false i.e.  listener is not going to be initiated.

Not working code -

```
 kafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.getAllListenerContainers().forEach(
  c -> ContainerTestUtils.waitForAssignment(c, 1));
```

Working code would be -

```
    kafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.getAllListenerContainers().stream().filter(c -> c.isAutoStartup()).forEach(
  c -> ContainerTestUtils.waitForAssignment(c, 1));
```

Consumer with autostartup false look like this -

```
  @KafkaListener(groupId = "${testgroupid", topics = "${testtopic}", containerFactory = "testContainerFactory", autoStartup = "${configValue:false}")
```

Note :-  by default value of **autostartup** is **true**